# Zend: Action Helper Pre-Dispatch Conditional on Route

Tags: zend-framework

I have two Action Helpers, one for Auth, and one for ACL.  For my default route, I am using the helpers' pre-dispatch hooks to fire them on every request (Auth first, then ACL).  I have a second route however, and for this route I only want Auth to fire.  (ACL is a non-issue for the second route).

What's the easiest way to get the ACL Action Helper to fire *only* on the default route?  I was thinking of putting an "if route = ..., then ..." in the action helper.  But is there a more elegant method?

Thanks!

Comment: `"if route = ..., then ...` is easy, intuitive and clear. I cannot think off any more elegant way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I had wondered if there was a way to configure the Action Helper on a per-route basis, but I'm happy with the consensus in the comments above.  I'll put an if-then in the ACL Action Heper.  Thanks!